# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\ln({3n^2 +4n+5})}{n^{4/3}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I test convergence for this series? I used limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}$ and seems to work, however I am looking for a simpler solution.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\ln({3n^2 +4n+5})}{n^{4/3}}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for all sufficiently large $n$, we have $\ln(3n^2+4n+5)<\ln(n^3)=3\ln(n)$. Now notice that for all sufficiently large $n$, we have $3\ln(n)<n^{1/6}$. Hence by the comparison test 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\ln({3n^2 +4n+5})}{n^{4/3}}}$$
converges if
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{1/6}}{n^{4/3}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{7/6}}$$
converges - which it does.